# Calculate position and indices in vertex shader

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I know that I can calculate vertices in vertex shader. But how can I specify indices in the vertex shader. Outside of vertex shader I create GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER buffer for indices and GL_ARRAY_BUFFER buffer for vertices. But what when I calculate those in vertex shader, how do I specify what are vertices and what are indices?

Comment: You don't do things like that. Vertex shaders are read-only. You actually never change either of those buffers, you just take some input vertex data and emit some new values for later stages to use. Later stages (generally) do not need to know about the vertex ID, if they do you can create a new attribute and write the value by hand.

Comment: Can I ask what you are actually trying to do here? A real answer should address that... what you are asking for is very unusual so you probably have some specific technique in mind.

Comment: I want to draw thick lines. To do so I take from user points and those points I want to send to the vertex shader using buffers. Thing is when zoom is small I want to draw those points using GL_POINTS, but when zoom is big enough I want to draw thick lines which vertices are computed inside the vertex shader. I need to use the indices since some vertices are repeated. Is this possible?

Comment: What you want sounds a lot like instancing, but it is not supported by OpenGL ES 2.0. I [*wrote an answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483586/android-opengl-2-0-sprite-optimization/19500921#19500921) roughly explaining how you can do this in the past, you might want to take a look at it and see if it makes any sense. It will involve actually duplicating the vertices in the buffer itself, rather than creating new ones in the vertex shader or at draw-time, but it is really the best you can do given ES 2.0's limitations.

Comment: Alternatively, you might just need `gl_VertexID`, I am not quite sure what information you *exactly* need in this situation because I have not seen any code. But again, you will have to do something very similar in ES 2.0 because `gl_VertexID` does not exist.